# Why is there quality loss on my image styles?

Tags: 7, media

This is the original image (610x405)

[image: Original Image]

This is the image after applying image style (scale and crop) to 290x190.

[image: After image styling]

Both image have the same aspect ration, yet there is visible quality loss on downsizing. Am I applying the right image style? What should I be doing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Under *admin/config/media/image-toolkit* there is an option to set the JPEG quality. By default this is 75%, so you should be able to up that to whatever you want.

[image: Image toolkit settings]

Comment: I did that...Yet don't see much improvement. Is scale & crop right, or should I be doing resize etc?

Comment: Did you flush the image styles caches before testing? changing this settings won't do that for you.

Comment: Okay, I flushed all cache via admin/config/development/performance (No drush), and I think it's better. (Looking at the same image makes you go crazy). But can you tell me is resize or scale&crop better?

Comment: @PratikBothra - I can't really answer that on a general level as it's totally up to your use case. I tend to use Scale and Crop more often than resize, though,

Comment: I succeeded in flushing the image styles caches only after "empty edit" of Image style, which was generating my thumbnail. (`admin/config/media/image-styles`)

Comment: I see the same thing, even with quality set to 100% there and with "resize" and "scale and crop" alike. Definitely a problem.

Comment: I had a serious image quality issue caused by having a maximum image size constraint in addition to a Scale & Crop on the field display. Removing the size constraint improved the output quality a LOT!

Comment: This solution didn't work for me in D9 version 9.2.10 :(

Answer (score 2):

You should use the following module :
[Image style Quality](https://drupal.org/project/image_style_quality)

> Set JPG quality per image style This module allows you to specify a
>   custom quality on different image styles you create. After installing
>   and enabling this module, you will have the option to add a new effect
>   to your image styles, enabling you to change the quality.
>
> Uses and Application Having high quality images is great and improves
>   the visual quality of your site. Problems can arise where you have
>   dynamic content such as a page background images that users can
>   upload. Having high image quality can lead to 2mb+ download sizes when
>   using full 1920x1024 image styles. With this module, you can scale the
>   quality of your large images down and leave your smaller thumbnails at
>   your defined default.